# Transforming screen position into image space

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, ogre

I'm trying to get a 2D screen position so I unproject a point from 3D into 2D screen coordinates by that following function:

```
Ogre::Vector2 SpaceTransformHelper::convertWorldToScreenPosition( const Ogre::Vector3& worldPosition )
{
    Stages::AStage* currStage = Stages::StageManager::getSingleton()->getActiveStage();
    Core::Resolution screenRes = Core::EnvironmentInformation::getSingleton()->getScreenResolution();

    // Get worldviewprojection from camera.
    Ogre::Matrix4 worldViewProjection = currStage->getActiveCamera()->getCameraViewProjectionMatrix();

    // Transform world coordinates.
    Ogre::Vector3 transformedWorldPosition = worldViewProjection * worldPosition;

    // Calculate screen coordinates from world coordinates.
    Ogre::Vector2 screenPosition;
    screenPosition.x = (int) ( ( ( transformedWorldPosition.x + 1 ) / 2.0 ) * screenRes.width + 0.5 );
    screenPosition.y = (int) ( ( ( 1 - transformedWorldPosition.y ) / 2.0 ) * screenRes.height + 0.5 );

    return screenPosition;
}
```

Now I want to convert that screenPosition into Image space to crop an image:

```
Core::Resolution screenRes = Core::EnvironmentInformation::getSingleton()->getScreenResolution();
float screenPositionX = (screenPosition.x / screenRes.width) * (pixelBuffer->getWidth());
float screenPositionY =  (screenPosition.y / screenRes.height) * (pixelBuffer->getHeight());
```

[image]

When I click on the mobile screen on the Green LED I get that cropped image.. but what I want is to only crop that green led.. Is there a problem with the transformation ?

```
   float screenPositionX = (screenPosition.x / screenRes.width) * ((int)pixelBuffer->getWidth());
        float screenPositionY= (screenPosition.y / screenRes.height) * ((int)pixelBuffer->getHeight());

       int  min_x = std::max( 0,(int)screenPosition.x - radius);
       int  min_y = std::max( 0,(int)screenPosition.y - radius);
       int  max_x = std::min( (int)cameraRes.width, (int) screenPosition.x + radius );
       int  max_y = std::min( (int)cameraRes.height, (int) screenPosition.y+ radius );

         // Get the pixelbox within the radius.
        pixelBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_READ_ONLY);
        const Ogre::PixelBox &readrefpb = pixelBuffer->getCurrentLock();

        unsigned char *readrefdata = static_cast<unsigned char*>(readrefpb.data);

        Ogre::Image img;
        img = img.loadDynamicImage (readrefdata, pixelBuffer->getWidth(),
                                    pixelBuffer->getHeight(), pixelBuffer->getFormat());

        Ogre::Image *out = cropImage(img,  min_x, min_y,  max_x,  max_y);
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks. Another question, There are Camera Resoultion, ScreenResoultion, Texture Resoultion... At which coordinate should I use for unprojecting the point to 2D Screen ? I guess Camera Resoultion ? I want then to work on the Image/Texture space and do some maniuplation

Comment: There are a couple of unclear things here: First of all, you're not "unprojecting", you are just projecting, unprojection would be the reverse operation. What is `getCameraViewProjectionMatrix();`, especially does it contain any perspective transformation? What happens to `w` when you do a `Vector3 = Matrix4 * Vector3` operation?

Comment: @derhass No it doesn't have any perspective transformation... I don't know what happens to w

Comment: @derhass please check the update post

Comment: @Rabbid76 Please check the updated post

Comment: When you project something 3D -> 2D you lose information, and that information cannot be restored.  There are infinite 3D points that happen to be in the same 2D position in your space.  Projections are known as having kernel space `!= ø`, so transformations will have `det(T) == 0` and you'll be unable to get the inverse matrix.